# Google app engine SDK and Java SDK version conflict

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, java-6

Trying to get started with Google App engine using Eclipse IDE. Adding the app engine support to Eclipse installs App Engine SDK 1.7.1. Simple app runs fine locally. But when you upload to the Google servers it won't run because it is compiled with Java JDK 1.7 and the Google App Engine servers are only compatible with Java 1.6 (SE 6).

OK, then you remove JDK 1.7 and install 1.6. Now it won't build because the App Engine SDK (1.7.1) is not compatible with JDK 1.6. Have spent a few hours trying to figure out how to install an older version of the App Engine SDK without success. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: GAE SDK 1.7 is compatible with Java6 and JDK 1.6. You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 1.7 configured in Eclipse, try setting the JDK Compliance to 1.6 (Java Compiler properties of your project).

Comment: Had already done this, but get this error on build in Eclipse: "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet." That's where I got stuck. However, with the comments posted here, I tried ignoring this error and running anyway. Now the program runs fine both locally and when I upload. When running locally, or when uploading you get the error warning, but if you ignore it, it works anyway. That's where I'm at, and thanks for the help.